# How to pass a POST value to a function after a redirect in a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass POST data to a function after performing a redirect. This is my code

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller {
    function myfunction1(){
        $data = array(
            'code' => $this->mymodel->myautocode(),
            'value1' => $this->input->post('value1'),
        );
        redirect(mycontrollers/myfunction2);
    }

    function myfunction2(){
         // now, how to pass $data in here
        $value2 = $value1
        $code1 = $code
    }
}
```

how to pass to myfunction2

Comment: invoke `myfunction1()` inside `myfunction2()`, make sure `myfunction1()` has a `return` statement

Comment: @MF.Hujaeri That doesn't make any sense. Passing values to a function is exactly what function arguments are for.

Comment: @EdCottrell i'm so sorry, thank you for correcting the title of my question, I am still in a learning phase CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, you have use session for this

```
function myfunction1(){
    $data = array(
        'code' => $this->mymodel->myautocode(),
        'value1' => $this->input->post('value1')
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect(mycontrollers/myfunction2);
}

function myfunction2(){     
    $value2 = $this->session->userdata('value1');
    $code1 = $this->session->userdata('code');
}
```

Comment: Not work well mean? Give your problem or requirement.

Comment: i need  to pass value from 'myfucntion1' to display in 'myfunction2'

Comment: you have to use the session for this, i have update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller {
    function myfunction1(){
        $data = array(
            'code' => $this->mymodel->myautocode(),
            'value1' => $this->input->post('value1'),
        );
    return $data;
    }
    function myfunction2(){
        $data = $this->myfunction1();
        $value2 = $data['value1'];
        $code1 = $data['code'];
//perform your operations here
    }
}
```